# How can I increase counter properties of class when a instance is called?

Tags: python

There is simple class:

> ```
> class A(object):
>
>     __COUNTER = 0
>
>     def do_something_1(self):
>         ...
>
>     def do_something_2(self):
>         ...
>
>     def do_something_N(self):
>         ...
> ```

Is there decision which can increase `self.__COUNTER` by calling method but not write it to each function?

I want as something as:

> ```
> a = A()
> # COUNTER = 1
>
> b = A()
> # COUNTER = 2
>
> c = A()
> # COUNTER = 3
> ```

Comment: Use a decorator: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808

Comment: Your question now has become ambiguous. Did you want to increment the counter when creating a new instance or when calling methods *on* the instances? Your example implies the first, but the rest of your question asks for the latter!

Comment: I am sorry if wrote ambiguous. I want increase when new instance

Comment: could you explain me why you need this functionality?

Comment: It is huger issue. Need to exchange with remote server which restrict max connection. It must no more 5. I use Django, Celery and MongoDB and I attempts build decision that can would check for maximum connections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hook into methods being called you'd have to use a decorator:

```
def increment_counter(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        self._COUNTER += 1
        return method(self, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

and apply this to each of the methods in your class:

```
class A(object):
    _COUNTER = 0

    @increment_counter
    def do_something_1(self):
        ...

    @increment_counter
    def do_something_2(self):
        ...

    @increment_counter
    def do_something_N(self):
        ...
```

Note that I renamed the counter to use *one* underscore, to avoid having to figure out the mangled name.

If you *must* have `__COUNTER` work (so with the double underscore), you could do that by passing in the name of the class:

```
def increment_counter(classname):
    counter_attribute = '_{}__COUNTER'.format(classname)
    def increment_counter_decorator(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
            setattr(self, counter_attribute, getattr(self, counter_attribute) + 1)
            return method(self, *args, **kw)
        return wrapper
```

Then decorate the methods with:

```
@increment_counter('A')
def do_something_1(self):
    ...
```

If you wanted to create a counter **per instance** instead, simply add to the counter *on the class*:

```
class A(object):
    _COUNTER = 0

    def __init__(self):
        A._COUNTER += 1
```

or use `type(self)._COUNTER` if you want to use a separate counter per sub-class of `A`.

Comment: Sadly - the update to the question has made this a lot simpler than the original question implied :(

Comment: Thanks for differents decisions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simple version: How to increment a class-wide counter every time a particular function is called. The function can be `__init__`, which covers your specific question.

```
class cls(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.counter += 1
        print self.__class__.counter

a = cls()  # Prints 1
b = cls()  # Prints 2
```

As you can see, the trick is to increment `self.__class__.counter`, not `self.counter`. You can do that inside any member function.

But don't use names starting with a double underscore, because they have special meaning for python (unless you know and want the special meaning, of course). If you want to flag the counter as private, use a single underscore: `_counter`.