# How increase and decrease counter by calling methods of instance?

Tags: python

[I asked sometime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233769/how-can-i-increase-counter-properties-of-class-when-a-instance-is-called) ago but this question more complex. I have instance of class and time to time calling a methods of instance. Example:

> ```
> class A(object):
>
>     __COUNTER = 0
>
>     def method_1(self):
>         ...
>
>     def method_2(self):
>         ...
>
>     def method_N(self):
>         ...
>
> inst = A()
> # call at one module
> inst.method_1()
> # call at other module
> inst.method_N()
> ```

When method was called I need increase a counter `__COUNTER`, but method is worked I need decrease the counter. Instance initialised at `__init__.py` and imported at some modules.

Can anybody help me with it?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean that the counter should be incremented while the method is executed, then decremented again? My decorator solution from my previous answer can do that trivially; instead of `return method(....)` you do `retval = method(....); self._COUNTER -= 1; return retval`.

Comment: I have many functions at the class. Is there lazy decision that watch itself calling methods and apply increase and decrease?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to keep track of call depth? If this is in order to profile your execution, there are all sorts of existing tools for that. And there are better ways to keep track of your call depth, so perhaps that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: @alexis no, I try to control maximum a connections to remote server

Comment: Is there also a multithreading/multiprocessing aspect to your application?

Comment: @alexis no, it without this aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust my decorator to decrement the counter again after the call:

```
def increment_counter(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
        self._COUNTER += 1
        try:
            return method(self, *args, **kw)
        finally:
            self._COUNTER -= 1
    return wrapper
```

The `finally` block will *always* be called, even if the method causes an exception to be raised.

Comment: I like this decorator, thanks.